# Indexes out of range, not finding the exact error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm essentially new to coding and I've been reading about Python. But I don't seem to find the error in my code. If you could help me with it, it would be great. Also any correction or observation is welcome.
I'm having this error:

**Code cause error**

```
if ((lista1[1] >= lista1[2]) and (lista1[2] >= 0)):
```

**Error:**

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**My Code:**

```
import math
import numpy as np

lista1=[1,3]

def von_mises(sigma_A, sigma_B, tao_XY):
    print("Las unidades de los valores ingresados se encuentran en kpsi")
    print("Ingresar el valor del esfuerzo en X:\n")
    sigma_A = input() #Input regresa una cadena de caracteres, no valores numéricos
    sigma_A = int(sigma_A)
    print("Ingresar el valor del esfuerzo en Y:\n")
    sigma_B = input()
    sigma_B = int(sigma_B)
    print("Ingresar el valor del esfuerzo cortante Tao:\n")
    tao_XY = input()
    tao_XY = int(tao_XY)
    sigma_von = math.sqrt((pow(sigma_A, 2))-(sigma_A*sigma_B)+(pow(sigma_B, 2))+(3*(pow(tao_XY, 2))))
    lista1 = np.array([sigma_von, sigma_A, sigma_B])
    return lista1 #para simplificar el llamado de los valores que arroja esta función

def ED(res_ced, lista1):
    print("Ingresar el valor de la resistencia a la cedencia:\n")
    res_ced = input()
    res_ced = int(res_ced)
    n_ED = res_ced/lista1[0] #se invoca a la función de von mises para simplificar
    print("El factor de seguridad ED es:")
    print(n_ED)

def ECM(lista1, res_ced):
    if ((lista1[1] >= lista1[2]) and (lista1[2] >= 0)):
        n_ECM = res_ced/lista1[1]
    elif ((lista1[1] >= 0) and (lista1[2] <= 0)):
        n_ECM = res_ced/(lista1[1]-lista1[2])
    else: 
        n_ECM = res_ced/(-lista1[2])
    print("El factor de seguridad ECM es:")
    print(n_ECM)
#MAIN
res_ced=0
tao_XY=0
sigma_A=0
sigma_B=0

ED(res_ced,von_mises(sigma_A, sigma_B, tao_XY))
ECM(lista1, res_ced)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, list indexing starts with 0. 
It should work if you change your code to

```
if ((lista1[0] >= lista1[1]) and (lista1[1] >= 0))
```

Comment: Yes i know, but the thing is that in that line i don't need the element lista1[0] , i need botch lista1[1] and lista1[2]

Comment: i don't think you have lista1[2] what did you expect to get returned ? @OsvaldoBouché

Answer (score 0):

It's  because python indexing starts from zero, so:

```
...

def ECM(lista1, res_ced):

    if ((lista1[0] >= lista1[1]) and (lista1[1] >= 0)):
        n_ECM = res_ced/lista1[0]
    elif ((lista1[0] >= 0) and (lista1[1] <= 0)):
        n_ECM = res_ced/(lista1[0]-lista1[1])
    else: 
        n_ECM = res_ced/(-lista1[1])
    print("El factor de seguridad ECM es:")
    print(n_ECM)
...
```

`lista1` is:

```
[1,3]
```

it only contains to elements,so since:

```
-------     -------
|  1  |     |  3  |
-------     ------- 

   0           1
```